# How to "dynamically add/ edit/cancel/ the textarea" in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

As, I am new to react I don't know how to perform dynamic add and edit and cancel operations on the textarea. I have dynamic array , i want to perform edit and cancel operations for every textarea individually . If I click on a edit button the mouse cursor should point to the specific textbox, and it should turn into editable mode . If, I click on cancel button  the specific textarea should turn into non-editable mode. [codesandboxdemo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-raman-l5eh0?file=/src/App.js:0-1763) please Run the code in codesandox and give me the solution

index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      
      count: [],
      disabled: false
    };
    this.newText = {};
   this.handleEdit = this.selectText.bind(this);
  }
  handleCancel(e,index) {
    this.setState({disabled:true})
  } 
  handleRemove(index)

  {
    this.state.count.splice(index,1)
     this.setState({count: this.state.count})
    
  }
  selectText(e, index) {
    newText = this.state.count[index];
     console.log(newText);
    this.newText.select();
 }

  add(e) {
   
    this.setState({ count: [...this.state.count, ""] ,disabled:false});
  }
  handleChange(e, index) {
    this.state.count[index] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>Enter the text</label>
        {this.state.count.map((counts, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
               
              <input
              
              ref={(newText) => (this.newText = newText)}
                onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, index)}
                value={counts}
               
                disabled = {(this.state.disabled)? "disabled" : ""}
                
               
              />
              <button    onClick={(e) => this.handleEdit(e,index)}>Edit</button>
              <button    onClick={() => this.handleRemove(index)}>Remove</button>
              <button  onClick = {(e) =>this.handleCancel(e,index)}> cancel  </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <button  onClick={(e) => this.add(e)}> Add</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

`][2](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-raman-l5eh0?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried doing it this way for you. This is not a complete answer (just to make sure I don't spoon-feed you, but this is a possible approach). Tell me if this works?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [Value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [EditMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);
  const toggleEditMode = () => setEditMode(!EditMode);
  return EditMode ? (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={Value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      onBlur={toggleEditMode}
    />
  ) : (
    <span onClick={toggleEditMode}>{Value}</span>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Click and it will make it editable. Come out and it shows updated value.

**CodeSandbox:** https://c4fog.csb.app/

Comment: it is working @ Praveen Kumar Purushothaman Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Pooja That's great. Thank you so much! 

Answer (score 0):

Here is full working code of App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: [],
      disabled: [],
    };

    this.references = []
  }

  handleRef(r, index) {
    this.references[index] = r
  }

  handleCancel(e,index) {
    const { disabled } = this.state;
    disabled[index] = true
    this.setState({ disabled })
  }

  handleRemove(index)
  {
    this.state.count.splice(index,1)
    this.setState({count: this.state.count})
  }

  handleEdit(e, index) {
    const { disabled } = this.state;
    disabled[index] = false
    this.setState({ disabled }, () => {
      this.references[index].focus()
    })
 }

  add(e) {
    this.setState({ count: [...this.state.count, ""] });
  }

  handleChange(e, index) {
    const { count } = this.state;
    count[index] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ count });
  }

  render() {
    const { disabled, count } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <label>Enter the text</label>
        {count.map((counts, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <input
                ref={(newText) => this.handleRef(newText, index)}
                onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, index)}
                value={counts}
                disabled ={disabled[index]}
              />
              <button onClick={(e) => this.handleEdit(e,index)}>Edit</button>
              <button onClick={() => this.handleRemove(index)}>Remove</button>
              <button onClick={(e) =>this.handleCancel(e,index)}>Cancel</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <button  onClick={(e) => this.add(e)}> Add</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: sure @ElektaKode